# Accessing the RoutingError URL in the error app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to access the URL that caused the routing error in my Error Controller.

**application.rb**

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

**routes.rb**

```
match "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
```

**Error controller**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout "error"

  def not_found
  end

protected

  def app_exception
    @app_exception ||= env["action_dispatch.exception"]
  end

end
```

How do I access the actual URL that caused the routing error? When I use `request.url` I get `\404`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `request.original_fullpath`.